# Designing WCF Contracts (Operation / Data)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, datacontract, operationcontract

I am currently looking to design some WCF services and wanted to get the community's opinion on the best way to handle operation / data contracts.

I have 2 basic operation contracts, the first **creates a quote** and the second **adds an item to a quote** (and calculates totals behind the scene).

The first takes in **customer information** and **store information** and **returns a quote**.

The second takes in a **quote** and an **item object**, calculates totals and **returns a quote with the item**.

My question is about how to design the data contracts in this scenario?

For the **CreateQuote**, should a quote object be passed in with a customer property and a store property set or should there be some kind of QuoteRequest object which contains a customer & store object but with no quote object passed in?

For the **AddQuoteItem**, should a QuoteItem object be passed in with required properties set including a Quote object or should there be a QuoteItemRequest object that has a Quote object and an item object (with no relation) and then a recalculated Quote with a QuoteItem object is returned?

In other words should they look something like this?

```
Quote CreateQuote(Quote quote);

Quote AddQuoteItem(QuoteItem quoteItem);
```

Or should they look something like this?

```
Quote CreateQuote(QuoteRequest quoteRequest);

Quote AddQuoteItem(QuoteItemRequest quoteItemRequest);
```

Comment: Enrique Albert has an excellent series of articles and sample code which discusses: Patterns and best practices for the desing and development of rich client enterprise applications using WPF, WCF and NHibernate. Check it out: goo.gl/XGo2 & goo.gl/raGM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that wrapping them in request/response wrappers might prove to be a little superfluous.  You can always presume that parameters to WCF service methods are the "request" and the return type is the "response".

In your scenario, pass a Customer type and Store type to the CreateQuote method and return a Quote type.  Then pass a Quote type and return either your Quote type again, or a bool indicating success instead, to the AddQuoteItem method.

Again in your scenario, your request/response classes would simply be one-level wrappers around a single type.  I could only envisage a scenario where you would return a response-esque class to wrap multiple different types in the method's single return value.

Comment: Thanks Adam - To clarify why I might want a QuoteRequest data contract - to hold 2 objects namely a customer and a store object (so it wouldn't be a "one-level wrappers around a single type" as you mentioned.

Comment: True, but you can have multiple parameters in a method signature, so it's not necessary for that.

Comment: I don't think that is the best solution. According to best practice articles service contracts should only have one parameter which wrap parameters.

Check out this article for more info: http://goo.gl/Qo9J

Comment: Good point; and there is your answer. If your service is likely to receive requests from MSMQ, then you will at some point need to wrap the parameters in messages. However, if it isn't going to, then you may end up over-complicating the public API of the service where you don't necessarily need to.

Comment: Don't forget, the solution only needs to meet your current business requirements leaving a sensible level of room for improvement/change.  Anything that doesn't fall into sensible shouldn't be catered for up-front.